# If statement within a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create a basic appointment system. When a user logs in, an `if` statement should display their personal appointments, but at the moment it's displaying everybody's appointments.

The aim of the `if` statement is to check their user ID to see if there are any appointments that use this user ID and display these appointments

My `appointments` table has a `user_id`, and my `users` table just has a regular `id`.

```
@section('content')
    <h1>Your Appointments</h1>
    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
        @if ($appointment->user->id == $appointment->user_id)
            <p>
                <a href="{{url('details/'.$appointment->id)}}" >{{$appointment->doctor->name}} : {{$appointment->time}} : {{$appointment->date}}</a>        
            </p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always display everyone appointments because you are comparing `appointment` associated `user->id` with the same `appointment->user_id`.

I believe you should change your `if` statement and compare it with logged in user session id like below:

```
$logged_user_id = Auth::user()->id;

@if ($logged_user_id == $appointment->user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this nested if statement we can reduce the logic in the view by selecting the appointments related to the authenticated user so in your controller instead of passing all the appointments we will do :

```
$appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
```

so in your view you can use only `foreach($appointments as $appointment)` to loop through them without needing to check if the appointment is related to the current user or not.